# How to send real-time output from Raspberry pi to my external computer?

Tags: python, deep-learning, raspberry-pi, prediction, real-time-data

I am working on a project where I need to send the output of my deep learning model (prediction model) that works on the raspberry pi to a remote computer where I can process that output in a database and plot the result and do other stuff to it.
The code and the format of the output is an array as shown in the picture.
The code:

```
from keras.models import load_model
# load model
model = load_model('C:\\Users\lenovo\Videos\saved_model.h5')
# summarize model.
model.summary()
import csv
import random
import time
import pandas as pd
from numpy import array
t = 0
v1 = 0
v2 = 0
v3 = 0
I1 = 0 
I2 = 0 
I3 = 0
I_N = 0
pr1 = ['V1_des', 'V2_des', 'V3_des', 'V_des',
       'I_des', 'mon_ph', 'C_circuit', 'sur_charge', 'Chute_tension']

pr = ['t', 'v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'I1', 'I2', 'I3', 'I_N']


with open('C:\\Users\lenovo\Videos\\file1.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=pr)
    csv_writer.writeheader()
while True:


    with open('C:\\Users\lenovo\Videos\\file1.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=pr)
        
        info = {
            "t": t,
            "v1": v1,
            "v2": v2,
            "v3": v3,
            'I1': I1,
            'I2': I2,
            'I3': I3,
            'I_N': I_N
        }

        csv_writer.writerow(info)
        

        
        t += 1
        v1 =random.randint(210,240)
        v2 =random.randint(210,240)
        v3 =random.randint(210,240)
        I1 =random.randint(210,240)
        I2 =random.randint(210,240)
        I3 =random.randint(210,240)
        I_N =random.randint(210,240) 
  
        x_input1 = array([v1, v2,v3, I1, I2, I3, I_N])
        x_input1 = x_input1.reshape((1, 7))
        print(x_input1)
        prediction = model.predict(x_input1)
        
        result = prediction.flatten()
        y = result.tolist()
        print(y)
        for i in range(len(y)):
    
            if y[i] != 0:
                default = i
            
                if default == 0:
                    print('Type of default: V1_des', y[i] * 100 , '%')
                elif default ==1:
                    print('Type of default: V2_des', y[i] * 100 , '%')
                elif default ==2:
                    print('Type of default: V3_des', y[i] * 100, '%')
                elif default ==3:
                    print('Type of default: V_des', y[i] * 100, '%')
                elif default ==4:
                    print('Type of default: I_des', y[i] * 100, '%')
                elif default ==5:
                    print('Type of default: mon_ph', y[i] * 100, '%')
                elif default ==6:
                    print('Type of default: C_circuit', y[i] * 100, '%')
                elif default ==7:
                    print('Type of default: sur_charge', y[i] * 100, '%')
                elif default ==8:
                    print('Type of default: Chute_tension', y[i] * 100, '%')

    time.sleep(1)
```

The output:

```
[[211 240 210 239 219 233 225]]
[0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
Type of default: V2_des 100.0 %
Type of default: V_des 100.0 %
[[219 217 225 234 229 239 217]]
[1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
Type of default: V1_des 100.0 %
Type of default: V3_des 100.0 %
Type of default: V_des 100.0 %
[[236 234 236 232 223 232 211]]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
Type of default: V_des 100.0 %
[[223 235 237 224 214 218 218]]
[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
Type of default: V3_des 100.0 %
Type of default: V_des 100.0 %
[[226 221 217 223 231 236 231]]
[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
Type of default: V1_des 100.0 %
Type of default: V_des 100.0 %
[[212 223 230 233 233 215 216]]
[0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
Type of default: V2_des 100.0 %
Type of default: V3_des 100.0 %
Type of default: V_des 100.0 %
```

Comment: Show code, output or error messages as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or external link.

Comment: I already did, please check it again

Comment: You could e. g. transfer the data by a network connection if both machines are connected to the Internet.

Comment: I was trying to make a socket connection to send the data but I couldn't figure it out how to include the output into the program to send it.

Comment: Do you want to store only your  results or the percentages derived from said results?

Comment: I can take only the results, the percentages aren't that much important for me.

Comment: You could e. g. send the string representations of the output lists and use "ast.literal_eval" on receiver side to convert them to list objects.

Comment: Actually, I'm new to all this, I don't know exactly what do you mean.  I found a code that sends simple messages but I couldn't integrate it with my code.

Comment: If you want some advice on how to send data from a Raspberry Pi to a PC you need to include more information... 1) what volume of data - 8 bytes or 3 MB? 2) how often - hourly? 50 times per second? 3) how are the two connected - bluetooth, serial cable, wifi, wired ethernet, SPI, I2C, LoRa? 4) what OS is the *"external computer"* running? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your raspberry pi connected in local network with your computer, You can use mqtt for send message realtime. see more http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/into-mqtt-python-client/

Comment: I'm not gonna use a local network for this process.

Comment: Yes, you can use mqtt same too.